# How can I add multiple lines in the title of a PDF output in Quarto using RStudio?

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to create a PDF file using Quarto in R. In the title, I want three lines: School Name, Exam (i.e., Annual or Mid-term) and Subject (i.e., Mathematics, Statistics, etc.). All these three elements will be in different lines. So, I tried using the following  code.

```
title: `r paste0("School Name", "\\linebreak ","Annual Exam","\\linebreak ","Mathematics")`
```

But this is giving me an error when I render the document. So, instead of one backtick, I also tried using three backticks. But still, I could not render the document. Can you help me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as the following,

```
---
title: |
  School Name \
  Annual Exam \
  Mathematics
format: pdf
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

The following also works,

```
---
title: |
   | School Name 
   | Annual Exam 
   | Mathematics
format: pdf
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

[image: multiline title]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use your syntax in the appropriate latex macros instead of having to deal with quarto making everything unnecessarily complicate...

```
---
format: pdf
header-includes: \AtBeginDocument{\title{School Name\linebreak Annual Exam\linebreak  Mathematics}\author{Mikey Mouse}\date{\today}\maketitle}
---

text
```

[image]